# Аналог функции js encodeURIComponent в perl

Tags: perl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, функцию в perl, аналогичную такой функции js,
как `encodeURIComponent`. То есть в js мы пишем:

```
var t = encodeURIComponent(document.title);
```

А в perl надо бы написать:

```
$t = xyz($title);
```

Какая функция perl будет эта "`xyz`"?

В JS составляем ссылку так:
`http://connect.mail.ru/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+
'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title));`

А в perl как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То есть, на CPAN и в гугле забанили совершенно? Первая же ссылка: [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.59/URI/Escape.pm)

Comment: Спасибо большое за URI::Escape! Так бы сразу и сказали.

Comment: Разработчики ХэшКода! Красную карточку тем, кто упоминает гугл! Без работы останетесь!

Comment: @welcomemyaltai красную карточку надо выдавать тем, кто гуглом пользоваться не умеет и задает такие вопросы. Ничего личного, просто тут не детский сад, а одно из важнейших умений программиста - находить инфу самостоятельно.

Comment: Шпионы с гугля у вас в... голове. Мне не принципиально, хоть яндекс, хоть яху, хоть поиск мэйл ру. Здесь не для ПРО, но и не ясли.

[Мнение администрации](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_8123.html)

**Сделайте все возможное сами.** Перед тем, как задать вопрос, попробуйте исследовать предметную область и найти ответ на вопрос. Если решение не удалось найти, приведите краткую сводку попыток решить проблему. Тем самым участники форума будут избавлены от необходимости искать информацию по теме и получат возможность сосредоточиться на главном - ответе на вопрос.

Comment: Через поиск нашел решения, такие как во втором ответе, то есть через регулярное выражение. Здесь же хотел спросить именно функцию. И первый же ответ дал подсказку:  

    #!/usr/bin/perl  
    use strict;  
    use URI::Escape;  
    # ...  
    $t = uri_escape($page_title);  
    $u = uri_escape($page_url);  
    print "http://connect.mail.ru/share?url=$u&title=$t";

Answer (score 1):

```
s/([^a-zA-Z0-9_.,-])/uc sprintf("%%%02x",ord($1))/eg;
```

Comment: Тогда уж:

    s/([^A-Za-z0-9_.~-])/sprintf('%%%02X',ord($1))/ge;

Согласно с `RFC-3986` или `RFC-3987` символ `','` нужно эскейпать, а `'~'` - нет

Comment: А на CPAN предлагается:
$string =~ s/%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
это не то?

Comment: это unescape.